# `FindMinimum` can't evaluate `Nearest` numerically

Tags: mathematical-optimization, numerics, evaluation, nearest

I'm trying to use `Nearest` as a function to minimize over: a toy example is

```
f[z_] := FindMinimum[First@Nearest[Range@9 -> "Distance", x], {x,z}]
```

An expected result is `f[5.6]=6`.  I'm aware there are simpler ways to write such a function; the goal is to minimze with `Nearest`.

I tried with `Unevaluated` and `Inactive` in various spots, but no matter what I get the error

> The default distance function does not give a real numeric distance
> when applied to the point pair x and 1.

Then `FindMinimum` complains about a nonnumeric function value.  It's worth noting that any symbolic call to `Nearest` gives the same error; the problem is that `FindMinimum` can't inject the parameter.

### Question

How can I properly delay the evaluation of `Nearest` such that it may be evaluated by `FindMinimum`?

---

Inadvertent solution:

```
f[x_] := First@Nearest[Range@9 -> "Distance", x]
FindMinimum[Hold@f@X, {X, 5.6}]
```

This doesn't seem to generalize when I do multidimensional minimizations.

Comment: No, `x` should be arbitrary.  For some reason extracting to a delayed function makes it work albeit with errors

Comment: Perhaps `f[x_?NumericQ] := First@Nearest[Range@9 -> "Distance", x]`?

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Nearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) is already doing a minimization, [`FindMinimum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html) is not needed.

```
First@Nearest[Range[9], 5.6]

(* 6 *)
```

To do a minimization with distance,

```
ArgMin[{EuclideanDistance[{x}, {5.6}], 1 <= x <= 9}, x, Integers]

(* 6 *)
```